# Relation between multinomial logit model and multi-class neural network

Tags: classification, neural-networks, multinomial-logit

I'm wondering how much differ in these two kinds of model when comes to predict discrete choice.

Consider a data-set explanatory $\boldsymbol{x}$ and response $\boldsymbol{y}$ where $\boldsymbol{y} \in \{0,1,2,\dots,K-1\}$ (total $K$ classes).

Multinomial logit do the prediction as follows ($y_{ij}$ represents the $i$-th person chooses $j$-th class)

$\mathbb{P}(y_{ij}) = \frac{\text{exp}(\boldsymbol{\beta}_j\boldsymbol{x}_i)}{\sum_{k} \text{exp}(\boldsymbol{\beta}_{k}\boldsymbol{x}_i)}$

where $\beta_j$ in which $j \in \{0,1,\dots, K-1\}$ are derived through maximum likelihood

It can also be written as

$$y_{ij} = \beta_jx_i + \epsilon_{ij}$$ and  $\epsilon_{ij} \sim$ i.i.d. standard type-1 extreme value distribution; then compute $\mathbb{P}(y_i = j) = \mathbb{P}(y_{ij} \ge y_{ij'};  \forall j')$.

The problem of multinomial logit is that $\epsilon_{ij} $ independent among each choice $j$ and leads to Independence of irrelevant alternatives. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_of_irrelevant_alternatives

Specifically; for any two choices $k,j$

$$\frac{\mathbb{P}(y_{ij})}{\mathbb{P}(y_{ik})} = \text{exp}((\beta_j - \beta_k)x_i)$$

This ratio does not depend on any alternatives other than $j$ and $k$. That is, the relative odds of choosing  $j$ over $k$ is the same no matter what other alternatives are available or what the attributes of the other alternatives are. Since the ratio is independent from alternatives other than  $j$ and $k$, it is said to be independent from “irrelevant” alternatives.

Now looked at deep neural network for multi-class prediction

$\mathbb{P}(y_{ij}) = \frac{\text{exp}(z_j)}{\sum_{k} \text{exp}(z_k)}$

where $z_j$ is the output of neural network. So simply using softmax activation in the last layer.

I'm wondering if neural network approach is same thing as first approach; can be alternatively written as

$$y_{ij} = z_j + \epsilon_{ij}$$

where $z_j$ is a very non-linear function of $x_j$ for all $j$; but I'm wondering if $\epsilon_{ij}$ here still i.i.d. follow standard type-1 extreme value distribution ? Or does $\epsilon_{ij}$ here actually correlated with other choice $j$ now so it can break the IIA assumption as mentioned above?